# Username and password creator

Tags: c#, beginner

This is the first program I have ever written outside of what I am learning in class.  I am in my first programming class (ever) in college and I'd like to know if this is any good or if I'm making glaringly bad habits and mistakes.  I am aware that some of the code I've written is redundant, but I don't think I've quite learned enough to fix it.

This program was created using Xamarin on my MacBook Pro, so the file structure built into the code is different from Windows and will have to be changed if you try to test it:

```
class if // under method FOR, change the string mainpath path to something windows

using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileCreator2
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 1;
            string useridtext = "NO VALUE";
            string passtext = "NO VALUE";
            string mainpath = "NO VALUE";
            string answer = "NO VALUE";
            string startup = "You have already created a username and password.";

            If ifs = new If ();

            ifs.FOR (counter, mainpath, startup, useridtext, passtext, answer);
        }
    }
    public class determiner
    {
        public void FilesExist(string mainpath, string startup, string useridtext, string passtext)
        {
            pause Pause = new pause();
            directory Direct = new directory ();

            if (Directory.Exists (mainpath))                                                                                
            {
                Console.WriteLine (startup);
            } 
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Create your username: ");
                useridtext = Console.ReadLine ();

                Direct.Create (useridtext, passtext, mainpath);

                Console.Clear ();

                Console.WriteLine ("Create your password: ");
                passtext = Console.ReadLine ();

                Direct.Create (useridtext, passtext, mainpath);

                Pause.Input ();
                Console.Clear ();
            }
        }
    }
    public class If
    {
        public void statement(string answer, string mainpath)
        {
            delete Del = new delete ();
            pause Pause = new pause ();

            if (answer == "Y") 
            {
                Del.Files (mainpath);
                Console.WriteLine ("Files deleted.");
            } 
            else if (answer == "y") 
            {
                Del.Files (mainpath);
                Console.WriteLine ("Files deleted.");
            } 
            else if (answer == "N")
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Here is the text in the file you created:");
                Console.Write ("Username: ");
                Console.WriteLine (File.ReadAllText (mainpath + "/userid.txt"));
                Console.Write ("Password: ");
                Console.WriteLine (File.ReadAllText (mainpath + "/passwd.txt"));
                Pause.Input ();
            }
            else if (answer ==  "n")
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Here is the text in the file you created:");
                Console.Write ("Username: ");
                Console.WriteLine (File.ReadAllText (mainpath + "/userid.txt"));
                Console.Write ("Password: ");
                Console.WriteLine (File.ReadAllText (mainpath + "/passwd.txt"));
                Pause.Input ();
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Invalid answer. Files not deleted, program terminated.");
            }
        }
        public void FOR(int counter, string mainpath, string startup, string useridtext, string passtext, string answer)
        {
            determiner determine = new determiner ();
            If ifs = new If ();

            for ( ; counter > 0; counter++) 
            {
                mainpath = @"/Users/kevgreenan/Desktop/PROJECT"; //this MUST change for WINDOWS users

                determine.FilesExist (mainpath, startup, useridtext, passtext);

                Console.WriteLine ("Would you like to erase the data (Y/N)?");
                answer = Console.ReadLine ();
                ifs.statement (answer, mainpath);
                Console.Clear ();

                Console.WriteLine ("Would you like to exit (Y/N)?");
                answer = Console.ReadLine ();
                if (answer == "Y") 
                {
                    counter = counter - 999999;
                }
                else if (answer == "y") 
                {
                    counter = counter - 999999;
                }
                else if (answer == "N")
                {
                    // this will start the statement over
                }
                else if (answer == "n") 
                {
                    // this will start the statement over
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Invalid input.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class directory
    {
        public void Create(string useridtext, string passtext, string mainpath)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (mainpath);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText (mainpath + "/userid.txt", useridtext);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText (mainpath + "/passwd.txt", passtext);
        }
    }

    public class delete
    {
        public void Files(string mainpath)
        {
            Directory.Delete (mainpath, true);
        }
    }
    public class pause
    {
        public void Input()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue. . .");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magus has already cleared the naming aspects so I won't talk about them. Except for this: drop everything and review your naming. Both conventions on how you structure them and actually thinking about whether or not the names for classes/variables really convey what they're about. At first glance, I have no idea what your code is about.

Onto something more functional:

**The DRY Principle**

DRY - [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) - is a very important aspect of creating a maintainable application. It makes sure that when you have multiple portions of code that do the same thing and you need to change that thing, that you will only have to make 1 change and not change it at every place in the code.

What if I want to change the default value to "NO VALUE LOL"? In your scenario, I'd have to change it 4 times.

Instead, look towards something like this:

```
string defaultValue = "NO VALUE";
string useridtext = defaultValue;
string passtext = defaultValue;
```

And now that issue is solved.

You do the same when checking if the input is "y"/"Y" or "n"/"N". Here the solution is not as straightforward, but you can make this more readable and maintainable by doing something like this:

```
if(answer == "n" || answer == "N")
```

or even better:

```
if (answer.Equals("n", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

[More about string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c-sharp)

---

**Getting loopy**

```
for ( ; counter > 0; counter++) 
if (answer == "Y") 
{
    counter = counter - 999999;
}
```

This is a very hacky way of making an infinite loop. On the bright side though: you have the right idea!

Let me first point out what's wrong with this approach.

1. Can you tell just by looking at the code whether or not what the intention was? Probably, but it's not as evident.
2. What happens if I'm really, really, really clumsy and I gave invalid input the first 1 million attempts but after that I get it right? It still won't end!

A better way of having an infinite loop is like this:

```
while(true)
{


   if(JeroenIsAwesome)
   {
       break;
   }
}
```

Obviously this will break from the first iteration. A slight note about this blueprint: a statement of the form `if(condition)` is evaluation as `if(condition == true)`, it's just shorthand. [The `break;` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) will exit the first enclosing loop it encounters, essentially ending the infinite loop.

---

**Namespaces? Boooooring!**

You have `using` statements available, use them. Using `System.IO.File` only serves a point when you have to distinguish between another class called `File`. Since you don't have that, all it does is make the code look more cluttered.

---

**Shorthands**

You can change this

```
counter = counter - 999999;
```

into this

```
counter -= 999999;
```

It's pretty cool. More on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691316(v=vs.71).aspx).

---

**User Experience**

Yep, you have to take them into account sometimes. This won't be very helpful for them to have it hardcoded:

```
mainpath = @"/Users/kevgreenan/Desktop/PROJECT"; //this MUST change for WINDOWS users
```

Instead, allow them to change it somehow. Either by entering it in the console or by passing it as a command line argument.

This is also begs the question: why pass it around as an argument when you overwrite it in that function anyway?

---

**Proper API**

The API - [Application Programming Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) - is made up of all methods you create. Typically you are interested in the *public API* which is what it says: the method calls that you can access as an outsider. As the developer of the API, you want to make sure that what you expose is something the outsider should be using and you avoid giving them access to stuff they should keep their paws off.

Now, in your situation it matters less but imagine someone is going to use your code and work with it. Does he need access to the `If#statement()` method, or does he need access to `MainClass#Main()`?

More on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).

Comment: if you want to name a variable `default`, it should be prefixed with `@` since it is a reserved keyword!

Comment: @TopinFrassi: aha, right! I didn't think too much of it and figured the syntax color was borked somewhere.

Comment: It's not much of a worry, but I think that the OP might not know about the `@` prefix

Comment: @TopinFrassi: That's likely true, but it is very rare for it to be a good idea to use it. There are cases when you'll want to use the name of a reserved word, but you can usually think of a name which gets the point across without the potential confusion. It's not something I'd encourage explaining to someone in their first programming course, especially since it would make some of those class names easier.

Comment: For the logical-OR operand, I tried doing something like  if (answer == "string1" || "string2") got an error and then moved on to what I knew would work.  Xamarin adds namespaces by default, I didn't clear it because I got lazy.  And as far as the mainpath variable, I was considering using some kind of OS detector (I think there is a method built in) with an if statement.  My biggest question is am I using too many if statements?  I felt like I over used them and could have somehow lumped them into one method.  I was trying to follow the "rule" of having short(ish) methods.

Comment: @Magus Right, I think the later someone learns how to do this the better it is, but I wanted to point it out anyway since it was part of the answer

Comment: @KevinGreenan: Everyone makes that mistake with logical operators at some point. But as for `if`s, most code has massive amounts of those. They're one of the most basic parts of programming. The structural issues have been pointed out above, though. Generally, you shouldn't have too many too close together. In those cases, you sometimes need a `switch` and sometimes need generics.

Comment: @Magnus: Also, I passed mainpath around to overwrite it to take care of an error to the tune of 'variable isn't defined' while also satisfying my preference of declaring all variables at the top of Main.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @KevinGreenan: I think the main thing your code currently lacks is data. You don't have to put variables inside of methods. You can put them directly in classes (as properties if they are public). But your main program and `Main` should generally have as little code as possible, unless you're writing a very simple, procedural application.

Answer (score 7):

First off, well done! Many first questions on this site don't even contain code which compiles!

Now for the review:

1. In C#, class names are expected to be in `PascalCase`. This helps your code look more like the surrounding framework code, thereby being more familiar to other programmers.
2. Likewise, local variables are expected to be `camelCase`
3. Classes are meant to hold some data and some behavior in most cases. They are typically named with nouns, because they represent objects. As such, `delete` is not a good name for a class; it's a verb, and a very *good* choice for a method name, provided it's obvious what is being deleted.
4. On the same token, nouns make lousy method names. Imagine the sentence "I will Files a delete." - that is how your code will be read.

A survey was once made to determine the hardest part of programming. Naming won. Generally, when you extract a method, it should have a name that conveys a bit of what it's doing. Calling a method on something named `If` does not tell you much about what that code is doing. You'd expect it to return true or false based on some kind of input, whereas yours is simply a wrapper for arbitrary conditional code. Consider what you'd call that step of processing, and use that name.

Overall, good work. Many people take entry level classes and cannot write a working `for` loop. Just the fact that you are seeking feedback this early on shows a lot of promise.